# Configuring VPS running OpenPanel for hosting with external nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, vps

I have a VPS running Debian 6.0 and OpenPanel.
With all the regulars already running(mysql, apache, php, etc)

Now, i ran into the problem with domains and DNS.
Im not really an expert in that area so pardon my ignorance.

We have couple of domains at Domainsite. They are providing their own nameservers.
So i added A record to one of our domains and pointed it to VPS IP.

Thats where i have some difficulty, how do i add the website/domain in OpenPanel and make it use external DNS. So far every panel i tried including OpenPanel wants me to setup master/slave DNS. Am i missing something?
How do i actually manage to point the right domain to the right site, when using external nameservers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the DNS in your panel to anything you like (normally, there should also be an option to disable it). It won't ever be queried, as the authoritative nameservers for your domain are stored at your registrar, and these ones will be queried by a client trying to open your website.

DNS is not needed internally on the server to point the right domain to the right site. This is achieved by the webserver configuration. In apache, the directives for this are

```
ServerName domain.tld
```

and

```
ServerAlias domain.tld
```

inside the vhost configuration. This way, apache knows that the following directives like `DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1/` are for this one domain.

Comment: Got it!
Basically with any control panel just create the domain/website and thats it. No need for any additional configuration, if you wont be using it(eg. you use external DNS) you can remove bind and everything related to it as its not really needed.
Thanks for clearing stuff up for me etagenklo :)